# Why is the new row not being renamed in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case, mysql-workbench

This is my code

```
SELECT *,
-- Add the status of the student depending on the CourseCode
(CASE
    WHEN CourseCode = 907 THEN 'Already in the course'
    WHEN CourseCode <> 907 THEN 'Upgraded to the course'
    Else NULL
END AS Status)
FROM ecestudents;
```

Unfortunately for some reason, it is throwing an error. But if I remove `AS Status` it is running properly, but I want to rename the new row I am creating using the case statement.

Comment: Change `END AS Status)` to `END) AS Status`

Comment: That's not "renaming a row", it's "aliasing a column"

Comment: True, because a row does not have a name in SQL. ( A column has a name)

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 1):

“AS status” should be outside the bracket. You don’t need the bracket as it is

Comment: We normally just make a comment on a TYPO and then delete the question, as typo's are never any real use to others

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets and run

```
SELECT *, 
CASE
    WHEN CourseCode = 907 THEN 'Already in the course'
    WHEN CourseCode <> 907 THEN 'Upgraded to the course'
    Else NULL
END AS Status
FROM ecestudents;
```

Comment: We normally just make a comment on a TYPO and then delete the question, as typo's are never any real use to others